# What's the best strategy to load the neighbor children around a specific child, preferably with one query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If we have the following object:

```
{
  "child01": {
    "rating": 1
  },
  "child02": {
    "rating": 2
  },
  "child03": {
    "rating": 3
  },
  "child04": {
    "rating": 4
  },
  "child05": {
    "rating": 5
  },
  "child06": {
    "rating": 6
  },
  "child07": {
    "rating": 7
  }
}
```

The goal is to obtain the previous 2 and next 2 children of a specific child, for example, the child with a rating equal to 4, preferably with one query.

The result expected is:

```
child02
child03
child04 (The child of interest)
child05
child06
```

My first guess was to use:

```
ref.orderByChild('rating').equalTo(4).limitToFirst(3).limitToLast(4)
```

But it seems we can't use both limits on the same time

Is there any way to query this in one request which I'm overseeing?

If not, what would be the best strategy to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have this complete JSON:

```
{
  "child01": {
    "rating": 1
  },
  "child02": {
    "rating": 3
  },
  "child03": {
    "rating": 3
  },
  "child04": {
    "rating": 3
  },
  "child05": {
    "rating": 5
  },
  "child06": {
    "rating": 3
  },
  "child07": {
    "rating": 7
  }
}
```

If you want the first three children with rating equal to `3`, you'd query:

```
ref.orderByChild('rating').equalTo(3).limitToFirst(3)
```

> child02
>
> child03
>
> child04

If you want the same, but starting at `child3`:

```
ref.orderByChild('rating').startAt(3, 'child03').limitToFirst(3)
```

> child03
>
> child04
>
> child06

If you want the next three siblings after `child3`, you can simply do:

```
ref.orderByKey().startAt('child03').limitToFirst(3)
```

> child03
>
> child04
>
> child05

For the working code, see http://jsbin.com/noziri/edit?js,console

Comment: Hi Frank, I was not clear enough on my question. I have edit the question hoping to have explained myself better this time. In short, can query the neighbours, both before and after, of a specific child with one query? (Better explained now above)

Comment: You cannot with a single query get children before **and** after. That will take two queries.